# Meaning of 'Life worth'

Tags: meaning

There is a book named **What is life worth** written by Kenneth Feinberg. 
 Is this a gramatically phrase?
 Or it must be what is life's worth?

Answer (score 4):

BOTH your example in question and your suggested alternative are correct grammatically but have slightly different meaning.

"Worth" can be both an *adjective* that *describes* the monetary value of something, but it is also an *abstract noun* when it acts as the *name* for the aggregated value.

> What is life worth?

This question is correct because it invites the reader to *reckon* or calculate, perhaps not literally, what the value of life is.

> What is life's worth?

Your alternative is also correct. As it uses the possessive form it assumes that the value of life has already been calculated, therefore you are asking what that value is.

It may help to consider the example of a house. If you were to ask:

> What is a house worth?

Every house has a different monetary value, so this non-specific question could be interpreted more generally, asking you to *consider* what any house may be worth to you. But...

> What is your house's worth?

This points to a specific house and a worth or value that has already been assigned to it.